# Develop organizational chart with REST

Tags: rest, organization-profile

Is there a way to build an organizational chart with REST? How do we get user manager and colleagues in REST, I guess I need to use profiles end point, but how do we build the structure for the web part itself, where do we start from?

I want to build my solution in JavaScript, as a SharePoint webpart or an hosted app, but I am not sure where to start getting profile info, do I get current user's profile and manager, then go up and down in the hierarchy? How do people build it?

Thank you.